# With golang and tls, how to convert rawCerts [][]byte (passed to VerifyPeerCertificate) to an x509.Certificate?

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate

**Context**: I want to establish a TLS Connection to a server, which has a certificate with a different (but known!) domain.

So I want to use `tls.Dial('tcp', 'real-domain', conf)`, but verify the domain of the certificate as if it would be the other domain (lets call it `wrong-domain`), of which I know the server should return it.

So I think the way to do this is override `VerifyPeerCertificate` in the clients `tls.Config`.

`VerifyPeerCertificate` gets `rawCerts [][]byte` as parameter, but to use `x509.Verify` I need the certificate as a `x509.Certificate` type.

**The question is**: How do I cenvert the `rawCerts [][]byte`, which are passed as a parameter to `VerifyPeerCertificate` converted to `x509.Certificate`?

**This is how I want to use it:**

```
    conf := &tls.Config{
        VerifyPeerCertificate: func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
            verifyOptions := x509.VerifyOptions{
                DNSName:                   "wrong-domain",
                Roots:                     serverCertPool,
            }
            cert := &x509.Certificate{???} // How do I get the x509.Certificate out of the rawCerts [][]byte parameter?
            _, err := cert.Verify(verifyOptions)
            return err
        },
        InsecureSkipVerify: true, // We verify in VerifyPeerCertificate
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`x509.ParseCertificate`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParseCertificate).

> ParseCertificate parses a single certificate from the given ASN.1 DER data.

Example: `cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCerts[0])`

By the way this is also how the function that calls `VerifyPeerCertificate` does:

```
// crypto/tls/handshake/handshake_client.go

func (c *Conn) verifyServerCertificate(certificates [][]byte) error {
    for i, asn1Data := range certificates {
        cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(asn1Data)
        if err != nil {
            c.sendAlert(alertBadCertificate)
            return errors.New("tls: failed to parse certificate from server: " + err.Error())
        }
        certs[i] = cert
    }

    // later on...
    
    if c.config.VerifyPeerCertificate != nil {
        if err := c.config.VerifyPeerCertificate(certificates, c.verifiedChains); err != nil {
            c.sendAlert(alertBadCertificate)
            return err
        }
    }
```